# Display not shown in Gnome Color!

Tags: 11.10, display, monitor, colors, color-management

I want to change the color profile for my display in Gnome Color but my display isn't in the list. How do I add my monitor, an Asus ML238, to Gnome Color? When I look at Display settings it says Unknown for my monitor, but the Nvidia settings successfully identify the make and model. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm using Ubuntu 11.10.

Thanks!

Comment: What video drivers are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The display probably shows up as "Unknown" because you are using the proprietary Nvidia drivers, which do not fully support the [RandR extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RandR).  You should still be able to associate a colour profile with the display though.

As far as creating a profile goes, you've got two options:

1. See if the display manufacturer provides an ICC profile for your display and add that.  This will only be an approximation, since different batches of the same model can differ slightly and a display can change over time.
2. Use a supported colour calibration device to create a profile for your display.  This will give the best results, but you will need the extra hardware.  A relatively inexpensive device is the [ColorHug](http://www.hughsie.com/), which was developed by the author of the colour calibration control panel.

Comment: I used a Pantone Huey and it worked great.

Answer (score 0):

Gnome Color doesn't work correctly with Nvidia driver.

If you want it to work as intended , you have to remove the Nvidia driver and replace by Nouveau. ( Check a lot of how-to on how to fall-back to Nouveau open-source driver ) Warning : Nouveau have for the moment weaker performances.

A solution to install a icc profile is to use http://dispcalgui.hoech.net : DispCalGUI
( you can download the Oneiric *.deb and install it into Precise if author don't have already packaged the new one, I tested it ). DispCalGUI is able to set a *.icc and create one with Nvidia driver and a colorimeter.

Note: for twinview/dualscreen/multiscreen ; it will apply only a single calibration profile on -both- screens. To set a different on each one, only Nouveau open-source driver can make it for the moment.

Comment: I ended up installing 12.04 and the monitor was recognized.